# Divisão não apresenta números após a vírgula

Tags: java, matemática, tipagem

Meu algoritmo em todos os testes de `println()`, está funcionando e na lógica também porém, os números após a vírgula ele não demonstram.

```
public class Exe27 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        int dividendo = 1;
        int numero = 0;
        double numHarmonico = 0;

        System.out.println("Sistema Harmônico");
        System.out.println("Digite em até que número a série irá");
        numero =scan.nextInt();

        for(int i = 1;i <= numero; i++) {

            numHarmonico += dividendo/i;
        }

        System.out.printf("%.2f", numHarmonico);
        scan.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim como o @Maniero já falou, o problema está na divisão de inteiros.

Uma outra possibilidade, é converter o valor durante a divisão:

```
numHarmonico += Double.valueOf(dividendo)/i;
```

Ou

```
numHarmonico += (double)dividendo/i;
```

Isso é apenas um exemplo, tenha em mente que a cada iteração você fará um cast.

---

O código completo ficaria mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        int dividendo = 1;
        int numero = 0;
        double numHarmonico = 0;

        System.out.println("Sistema Harmônico");
        System.out.println("Digite em até que número a série irá");
        numero =scan.nextInt();

        for(int i = 1;i <= numero; i++) {
            // Outro exemplo de conversão
            // numHarmonico += Double.valueOf(dividendo)/i;
            numHarmonico += (double)dividendo/i;
        }

        System.out.printf("%.2f", numHarmonico);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/WorthlessBleakScientist

Comment: Resolveu Perfeitamente!

Answer (score 3):

Está dividindo por um número inteiro, então o resultado será inteiro, mesmo que depois isso seja guardado em um variável do tipo `double`. Primeiro ele faz a conta e depois guarda, no momento que faz a conta usando inteiros o resultado não considera onde será guardado, só o que precisa para a conta. Trocando o tipo de um dos operandos resolve a questão:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Sistema Harmônico");
        System.out.println("Digite em até que número a série irá");
        int numero = scan.nextInt();
        double numHarmonico = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= numero; i++) numHarmonico += 1.0 / i;
        System.out.printf("%.2f", numHarmonico);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3tnAXW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/DoubleDivisionjava). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/DoubleDivision2.java).

Comment: Resolveu perfeitamente!